# Download file from server not work with videos/ large files

Tags: php

I've just faced an problem. When I download normal files such as images and stuff from my server, works just fine. But when I have an .mp4 file it not work at all, site just die.

Remember my code first extract the file, and then get the full path.
The code I use to download is:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($afterExtract));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($afterExtract));
ob_clean();
flush();
return readfile($afterExtract);
```

Comment: `"site just die"` isn't an accurate enough description. How does it `"just die"`? What errors are there? Have you tried debugging? -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Remember that MP4's are larger than images. Make sure the MP4's are smaller than the limit you have on them.

Comment: Hmm it may sounds weird, but when I use `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` it just download without any problems.

Comment: But the video is not working

Comment: Open the downloaded video file in Notepad or some other text editor and check its end. There might be a PHP error message in there. Or better yet, comment out the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers to see it in the browser.